# iisexpress.exe has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.net web application. Whenever I am trying to execute that application it suddenly stops and throws an error:

> The program '[6648] iisexpress.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).

I am unable to solve that problem.

Can any one suggest me or solve my problem?

Comment: Can you add some code from Global.asax, application_start?

Comment: @Sunil No haven't add any code in any file.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem Solved..

I had deleted hidden .vs folder from Solution